# Bizarre behavior about network tab of remote debugging

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I use remote debugging of devtool to debug a webpage in Android.
I have learnt that devtool first downloaded some file([filename screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnANv.png)) necessary to debug page of webview.

However, when i clicked the filter of **Network** tab, something strange happened.
For example, i click **XHR** filter with the expection of filtering only xhr request, but only to toggle other filters than **XHR** tab, like **All**, **JS**, **CSS**, **Img**...[gif of bizarre behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTla2.gif)

I used remote debugging before, but didn't encounter this strange behavior.
Is this the problem about version? I can't control the version of file which is downloaded by devtool.
Is this an official problem? Please help me, thank in advance!

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Comment: @wOxxOm Do you mean that it's the bug of chrome?